# Why do we have to import keras from tensorflow if we have already imported tensorflow in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, keras, python-import

I'm now learning tensorflow and keras and I see all tutorials have these two imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

Based on my understanding of python import, I thought the second line was an extra, since if we have already imported tensorflow in the first line, then we shall have imported every module in tensorflow. Just like if we have

```
import math
```

then we shouldd have math.log(), math.sqrt() available.

However, if I comment

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

then this line of code

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
```

would return
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-3-740ba65f0ade> in <module>()
----> 1 model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])

NameError: name 'keras' is not defined
```

Why can't we directly use **tf.keras** if we only have **import tensorflow as tf**? What's special about this import compared to the import in **import math**?

Thanks

Comment: ```print(tf.__version__)``` gives me 1.14.0-rc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not with `tf.keras`. In your model definition, you use `layers` from `keras` and not `tf.keras`. That's why your'e getting the error when you remove the import. Replace your model definition with:

`model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])`

Now, you do not need to import `keras` from `tensorflow`.

Comment: Thank you every much Vishnu! Indeed as you said and I verified it! So the  only benefit of this ```from tensorflow import keras``` is just to write ```keras``` more conveniently, like we don't have to write ```tf.keras``` every time, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever you find convenient. I prefer `tf.keras`.

Answer (score 5):

When you import a module in python, you import only that module (along with the modules imported by the module), any modules defined in the imported module need to be imported on their own,

example

```
$ ptree
.
├── imports.py
└── pmod
    ├── cmod.py
    └── __init__.py

1 directory, 3 files

$ cat imports.py 
import pmod

pmod.do()
pmod.cmod.do()

$ python3 imports.py 
hello from pmod
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imports.py", line 4, in <module>
    pmod.cmod.do()
AttributeError: module 'pmod' has no attribute 'cmod'
```

however if I import it explicitly it does work

```
$ cat imports.py 
import pmod
import pmod.cmod

pmod.do()
pmod.cmod.do()

$ python3 imports.py 
hello from pmod
hello from cmod
```

Comment: Thanks a lot YHoffman! May I ask where is ```pmod.do()``` defined? It seems to me ```pmod``` is a directory rather than a python file

Comment: It is defined in the `__init__.py` file, that is what gets imported when. You do an `import`, now you can also define in the `__init__` file `import cmod` and that will in effect hoist up the import and allow you to do `pmod.cmod.do()` without explicitly importing it as it will already be imported as part of pmod

Comment: I see that with tensorflow and keras it is already imported, (most probably using the `init` file). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help YHoffman! Now I understand how "import" works in python. I appreciate it! 